# how to get SQL to process an aggregate in a specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query for SQL Server 2012 that will return a varbinary value where the bits in the value represent permissions to specific modules in our system.  So, for example, if I have access to modules 1, 4, and 10, the query would return 0x0209 (bits 1, 4 and 10 are on)

I have the query that will return each byte of the binary value in a separate row (bear in mind that this is a query to return some specific values for testing the logic only):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), CONVERT(varbinary(1), SUM(POWER(2, ((ModuleID-1)%8)))),2) AS ByteMask
     , (ModuleID-1) / 8 AS ByteNumber
FROM Gideon.Permission
WHERE IsBaseModulePermission = 1
AND ModuleID <> 3
AND ModuleID <> 8
GROUP BY (ModuleID-1) / 8
```

This returns:

```
ByteMask  ByteNumber
  '7B'       1
  'FF'       2
  '01'       3
```

ByteMask is a VarChar and I need to combine these into a string ordering by ByteNumber DESC.  So the result would be 01FF7B.  I will then convert this string to a varbinary.  I have a user defined aggregate function called Concat which will concatenate the strings for me.  So the query

```
SELECT dbo.Concat(DrvTable.ByteMask, '') AS ByteString
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), CONVERT(varbinary(1), SUM(POWER(2, ((ModuleID-1)%8)))),2) AS ByteMask
         , (ModuleID-1) / 8 AS ByteNumber
    FROM Gideon.Permission
    WHERE IsBaseModulePermission = 1
    AND ModuleID <> 3
    AND ModuleID <> 8
    GROUP BY (ModuleID-1) / 8
) AS DrvTable
```

will return a VarChar of '7BFF01'

Here is where I get stuck.  The value that needs to be returned is '01FF7B'.  The concatenation of the ByteMask strings needs to be ordered by the ByteNumber DESC.  Placing a TOP 100 PERCENT and ORDER BY on the derived table has no effect on the outcome.  You can't use an OVER clause on a user defined aggregate function.

So, I am hoping that someone will either have a totally different way to accomplish this goal or will be able to tell me how I can get the rows from the derived table delivered to the Concat aggregate function in a specific order.

Comment: This would seem like an efficient way to bitmask permissions back in the 1970s but in today's relational databases it's much more trouble than it's worth. IMHO.

Comment: Also, the TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY is nonsense and a no-op. You want ordered grouped concatenation? [Use FOR XML PATH](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d59bd/1).

Comment: Thank you @AaronBertrand for your comments.  Your first one actually got me thinking that I might want to take a different approach here.  I will investigate that tomorrow.  But in the event I stick with this, the FOR XML PATH example will be very useful.